# How to generate ggplot from results of SQL query?

Tags: r, sql-server, ggplot2

I'm new to R I try to generate word frequency plot from results of this SQL query by ggplot2 function.

What the correct parameter to ggplot2 function?

```
select AreaType 
from AreaOFInterest a, Projects p 
where p.Id = a.Id;
```

I want to display the frequency of each AreaType

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)

conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = dbConnection)
df <- sqlQuery(conn,  iconv(paste(readLines('c:/users/comnet/source/repos/rproject3/rproject3/sqlquery.sql', encoding = 'UTF-8', warn = FALSE), collapse = '\n'), from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII', sub = ''))   
ggplot2(data=df,aes(x=#What should be x, y=#What should be y))
```

Comment: Look at the column names of your data frame, `names(df)`. If you have a column named "hello" that you want on the x-axis, and another named "world" you want on the y-axis, use `aes(x = hello, y = world)`.

Comment: By the time your `df` is in R, it doesn't matter that it came from a SQL Server connection. I'd recommend reading an intro to ggplot2. Any intro will cover basics like this.

Comment: data frame is the results of query contains only AreaType (type1,type2, type3, type1,type1 etc )

Comment: Well, then you'll need to transform your data so it has columns for what you want on the x axis and what you want on the y axis. You should also think about what kind of plot you want - scatterplot? line plot? barplot?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged